# ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\SB.UBTC.RUCC]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bios, acpi

I've just bought myself a fresh new mini pc with a pre-installed Windows 11 Pro. After setting up Windows 11 with the first boot just to check if everything is fine, I tried to install Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS however it failed.

**Details of the PC:**

Intel Core I7-1060NG7 with Intel Iris Plus graphics;
16GB LPDDR4 RAM & 1TB NVMe SSD;
BIOS Vendor: American Megatrends
Core Version: 5.14
Compliancy: UEFI 2.7; PI 1.6
BIOS version:V1.3_226
Project Version: Intel
EC Version: V1.3

During the boot from USB, the GRUB appears, and I got several choices such as:

- Try or Install Ubuntu
  Ubuntu (safe resolution)
  Boot from other partition
  UEFI Firmware settings*

From the options above, only Ubuntu (safe resolution) initiated the system.

Choosing the Try or Install Ubuntu, I receive the following message lines and then the screen blacks out.

```
[ 0.173619] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[ 0.374473] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)
[ 0.374500] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)
[ 0.374562] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)
[ 0.374579] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)
[ 0.405602] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)
[ 0.405625] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB.PCI0.TXHC.RHUB.SS01._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)
[ 0.405687] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)
[ 0.405687] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB.PCI0.TXHC.RHUB.SS02._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)
[ 1.043180] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)
[ 1.043215] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)
[ 1.043326] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)
[ 1.043366] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)
[ 1.043931] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)
[ 1.043960] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)
[ 1.044124] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)
[ 1.044152] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)
```

[Code Lines after trying to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uJV3.jpg)

I can't install the distro on the pc. The system won't load beyond this point, no matter how much time passes. I have to manually turn off the computer.

Tried different distro (Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS) and even later versions(Pop!_OS 21.10 LTS and for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).
For flashing the USB, I tried Rufus (I even tried Ubuntu with FAT32 or with NTFS, just because of BMAX proposal on their offical webpage), then Etcher and even Ventoy.
The USB stick I used works as I used it for my other PC's installation and there was no problem.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot